# How Would I Appropriated Add this Route?

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

I've got an ASUS RT-AC66u running an OpenVPN server working fine.

But on my debian server I have to add a route or else I get no responses.

Just curious if there is a way to add the route to the router for persistence there, versus putting the command in /etc/network/interfaces as a post-up/pre-down rule.

On debian I've added this:

```
route add -net 10.14.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.192.2
```

I tried adding basically the same thing to the ASUS (not realizing that obviously shouldn't work) and broke any connection until I removed it.

Would the proper syntax for it be?

```
net 192.168.192.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw put.vpn.gw.here
```

Answer (score 0):

you can edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add a new stanza like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
      address Your_Interface_IP_addreess
      netmask Your_Interface_netmask
      up route add -net 10.14.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.192.2
```

if there are more than one static routes going out from the same interface, you can repeat the `up route` line with the information regarding the other network(s) and gateway(s)

Comment: That is my current method, along with loading iptables from a save. But I was more curious how to get the router doing that part...if that is an acceptable method to accomplish it by.

Comment: if you only have one network interface on your asus and you want all the traffic go out of this interface, you can just set the default route and forget the rest. If you are distributing network traffic to more than one interface, you need to specify the route one way or another on your system.

Comment: Kk, so the openvpn is on tun (tun21 to be precise), and then of course the network is going out eth0 for the most part (debian box is hardwired). Im just wondering if I add any other servers over time if they'll need the same route addition, and if the router itself could have one setting versus putting route on all computers.

Comment: routers are capable of doing this but how is your server going to know which interface  to send the packets to, if you do not have a routing table for that server ? Think about it.